# Memory leak when creating matplotlib.plots in loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, memory-leaks

I know it was discussed not only once.  Unfortunately, I do not get further.

first the basic:
I am trying to loop through OHLC data and create charts. Unfortunately the memory keeps running full.

Apparently it has something to do with the size of the chart.

```
plt.ioff()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(50, 25))

for line in ohlc_data:

   # Make magic with the data
   # ...

   df = x.get_ohlc_data()
   ohlc_area = plt.subplot2grid((6, 3), (0, 0), colspan=3, rowspan=4)
   ohlc_area.plot(df[['Date']], df[['close']], 'k-', markevery=markers_on, marker='D',
                                                       label='close')
   plt.grid(axis='x', color='0.95')
   plt.grid(axis='y', color='0.95')
   plt.savefig("Diagramme/" + str(x.id) + "_" + x.state + ".png")

   # Try to clean up everything
   fig.clf()
   plt.cla()
   plt.clf()
   plt.close('all')
   gc.collect()
```

Up to this point it works. Unfortunately fig.clf() also resets the size of the diagram. If I try to resize the diagram within the loop, there is a memory leak and I don't understand why.

```
plt.ioff()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(50, 25))

for line in ohlc_data:

   # Make magic with the data
   # ...

   #plt.figure(figsize=(50, 25))
   plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (50, 25)
   #fig = plt.figure(figsize=(50, 25))

   df = x.get_ohlc_data()
   ohlc_area = plt.subplot2grid((6, 3), (0, 0), colspan=3, rowspan=4)
   ohlc_area.plot(df[['Date']], df[['close']], 'k-', markevery=markers_on, marker='D',
                                                       label='close')
   plt.grid(axis='x', color='0.95')
   plt.grid(axis='y', color='0.95')
   plt.savefig("Diagramme/" + str(x.id) + "_" + x.state + ".png")

   # Try to clean up everything
   fig.clf()
   plt.cla()
   plt.clf()
   plt.close('all')
   gc.collect()
```

I tried at the beginning of the loop with:

```
   #plt.figure(figsize=(50, 25))
   plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (50, 25)
   #fig = plt.figure(figsize=(50, 25))
```

Unfortunately it does not work, can someone tell me how I can prevent the memory increase or how this problem comes about?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems this line `ohlc_area = plt.subplot2grid((6, 3), (0, 0), colspan=3, rowspan=4)` is creating a new axis every loop iteration ... Is that what you want to do ? You should create all axes outside of the loop, and then refer to them within the loop. Use the axis methods ax.plot and ax.clear

Comment: Hello unfortunately this also does not work!

Comment: you can also comment out all of the matplotlib code, and see if your memory leak persists .  Also - what is `gc.collect()` doing ?

Comment: Commenting out the code to create the diagram was one of the first things I did to get to the bottom of the problem. If I don't create the diagrams, there is no Menory leak!

`gc.collect()` was an attempt to start the garbage collector by hand. i found the tip in some posts, but i don't think it is necessary. i will remove it again.

perhaps I have not understood your tip with the Axis correctly or converted. altogether 3 diagrams are to be provided
I had 2 of the 3 diagram but removed so that the code is clearer.

Comment: Also, its unclear what this particular line does: `df = x.get_ohlc_data()` , so its hard to diagnose from afar. I would comment out that line, and replace df[['Date']], df[['close']] with dummie arrays..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but perhaps moves you in the right direction.

You are creating a new plot axis during each for loop iteration with the call to subplot2grid. Move this outside of the loop completely:

```
plt.ioff()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(50, 25))
ohlc_area = plt.subplot2grid((6, 3), (0, 0), colspan=3, rowspan=4)

for line in ohlc_data:

   # Make magic with the data
   # ...


   df = x.get_ohlc_data() 
   
   ohlc_area.clear()
   ohlc_area.plot(df[['Date']], df[['close']], 'k-', markevery=markers_on, marker='D',
                                                       label='close')
   ohlc_area.grid(axis='x', color='0.95')
   ohlc_area.grid(axis='y', color='0.95')
   plt.draw()
   plt.pause(0.1)
   plt.savefig("Diagramme/" + str(x.id) + "_" + x.state + ".png")

   # remove the other lines where you were attempting garbage cleanup... the ohlc_area.clear() should clean the axis during each iteration so you can make and save a new plot ...
```

Also, you can remove all the garbage cleanup stuff/

Note, there are a lot of unknowns for someone reading your code, for example   `df = x.get_ohlc_data()` , I have no idea what thats doing, and it could also be creating some kind of memory leak. Best to reduce your problem to something others reading your post can run on their end and observe the memory leak ...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes that's right some things are hard to understand. the mentioned line returns a numpy array containing the collected data. I had already tried to redicate the code in the hope that I don't leave out anything important. I had already tried to make the definition outside the loop. Unfortunately then the diagrams remain completely empty! I openly admit that I do not understand the lib very well, because it does not behave typically! Nevertheless, thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: I added another two lines you could try. Sometimes its necessary to call `plt.draw` and `plt.pause` depending on whether you are in an interactive environment ... Good luck!